# Advantages and disadvantages of the pickle, JSON and CSV methods for saving a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've researched multiple methods for saving a dictionary, such as pickle, JSON and CSV, but I don't see anywhere with the benefits or restrictions of each of these methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**`pickle`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

On the plus side, it can handle arbitrary objects (with varying levels of work). On the minus side the flat format is not human-readable, and it shouldn't be used with untrusted input. There are versioning issues, too; there are various different protocols defined.

[**`json`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

It's easy to move back and forth between some container (`dict`, `list`) and value (string and number) objects and JSON. It's also generally human-readable (subject to *"pretty"* formatting), widely used and well-supported by most (all?) languages. It can't handle arbitrary objects like pickling can, though.

[**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

Arguably the simplest format, but won't handle nesting well while remaining readable and easy to parse (it's probably best suited to persisting a simple table). There's generally more work to convert back and forth than JSON or `pickle`, too.